# How do I get Ricoh Aficio GXe3350n to print?

Tags: printing

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and it recognizes the printer and everything, but it doesn't print the jobs on the queue, until I turn the printer off and on again.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: have you selected the right printer? E.g. you might unintentionally be printing to your default printer instead of the GXe3350n...

Install the Gutenprint and the CUPS drivers from the software center and restart your machine.